# Apache: Extracts parts of variables from rewrite rules in headers

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have a rewrite map associating pictures hash to the real path (to be kept secret) of the picture.
With a single rewrite rule I can give back the picture with the hash as the url, that's fine.

However this is the path that I would like to keep secret, not the picture name.
Even if the name is not secret, I don't want users to directly access with server/image_name.jpg
I thus think that providing the filename in the content-disposition header is OK.

I came up with this:

```
RewriteMap redirector txt:C:/Apache24/url-mapping.txt
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/i/(.*)$ ${redirector:$1} [E=filename:${redirector:$1}]
Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=%{filename}e"
```

But the mapping is of this shape:

```
fa54e01623f625b1a6160fa0fee24112 /images/apath/to/picturename.png
```

And the current configuration takes the whole path, not the last part.

So my questions are:

1. is there another way to achieve what I want to do?
2. with the Content-disposition solution, how and where can I take a part of my variable filename to really have the filename?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution (using a dummy rewrite):

```
RewriteMap redirector txt:C:/Apache24/url-mapping.txt
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/i/(.*)$ ${redirector:$1} [E=path:${redirector:$1}]

RewriteCond %{ENV:path} .*images.*/(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [E=filename:%1]
Header set "Content-disposition" "attachment; filename=%{filename}e"
```

with the following kind of rules in url-mapping.txt:

```
fa54e01623f625b1a6160fa0fee24112 /images/myimage.png
```